# Sumar cantidades entre input number

Tags: javascript, input

Tengo estos dos inputs number, donde pretendo que mientras la cantidad aumente, al input de abajo se le sumen, eso si lo hace el problema es que, por ejemplo si la cantidad de abajo es 63 y el input de arriba esta en 4 al bajar a 3, en el otro en vez de restarle le suma.

Como le puedo hacer para restarle cantidad?

```js
function extra() {
    const $total = document.getElementById("Consumo_Asignado");
    let subtotal = 0;
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("monto")].forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.value !== '') {
            subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
        }
    });   
        $total.value = subtotal + parseFloat($total.value);  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<input type="number" onchange="extra();"  class="form-control monto" id="Consumo_extra" style="text-align: center; color: #523e02; font-weight: bold; ">
</div>


<div class="row">
<input value="50" type="number" class="form-control" id="Consumo_Asignado" style="text-align: center; color: #523e02; font-weight: bold; " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te pasa eso porque no estás guardando el valor original.

Tu dices que

- Arriba tienes 4
- Abajo 63

Cuando disminuye de 4 a 3, lo que haces es `63+3 = 66`, y si luego pasas de 3 a 2, haces  `66 + 2`

Puedes guardar el valor original en un atributo `data-valor` y realizar las operación a partir de él

```js
const $total = document.getElementById("Consumo_Asignado");
const original_value =  Number($total.getAttribute("data-valor"));

function extra() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".monto").forEach(e => {
         $total.value = original_value + Number(e.value) 
    });    
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<input type="number" oninput="extra();" value="0"  class="form-control monto" id="Consumo_extra" style="text-align: center; color: #523e02; font-weight: bold; ">
</div>


<div class="row">
<input value="50" data-valor="50" type="number" class="form-control" id="Consumo_Asignado" style="text-align: center; color: #523e02; font-weight: bold; " />
</div>
```